# Unable to load Arc Binary Grids in QGIS

Tags: qgis, esri-grid-format

I have a single band 32-bit integer Arc Binary Grid.  Using QGIS 2.12.3, when I try to add this Grid, it is listed in the table of contents, but nothing shows in the map window.

To add the Grid, I use the "Add Raster Layer" button and select the w001001.adf file from within the Grid's folder.  I've successively used this method in the past with previous QGIS versions on other Grids, and have confirmed the process at https://pvanb.wordpress.com/2010/03/15/esri-rasters-in-grass-or-qgis/

QGIS reports that the min/max values are both -1.14848e+06.  However, when I view the Grid in Arcmap 10.0, min and max are correctly reported as 1,000 and 1,000,000, respectively.

As a test, I converted the Grid to a Tiff using Arc.  QGIS reads this Tiff correctly.  Although I can use the Tiff for my project, I would like to understand why I cannot add the .adf into QGIS.

Comment: The min/max values in QGIS are usually 2% / 98% values. What do you get if you change the rendering extent to 1000 and 1000000?

Comment: do you have nodata values in your raster data? just recently i  had a similar problem where qgis identified min to be  3.xxx e-35 ... acording to metadata description that value represents "NoData". i had to set min max manually and then to push the "classify" button  subsequently.